# Keyboard enter key not working in appium java-client 6.0.0-BETA2

Tags: appium, java-client

i'm trying automate the search scenario, i mean pass one text to input field and hit enter button of keyboard.

so far, i tried below:

1. `((AndroidDriver)driver).pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.ENTER);`
2. `driver.getKeyboard().sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);`
3. `driver.press_keycode(66)`
4. ```html
       Robot robot;
       try {
           robot = new Robot();
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
       } catch (AWTException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   ```

and, i'm using `java-client 6.0.0-BETA2`

can anyone help in this?

Screenshot: [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code. It must work:

```
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import io.appium.java_client.android.nativekey.AndroidKey;
import io.appium.java_client.android.nativekey.KeyEvent;

((AndroidDriver<MobileElement>) driver).pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.ENTER));
```

> Before using enter key, you must first **click** on text input field.

Comment: cannot import "import io.appium.java_client.android.nativekey.AndroidKey;" and 
"import io.appium.java_client.android.nativekey.KeyEvent;". May i know which java-client version you are using

Comment: It is working fine for java-client version 6.0.0 and above. Why are you using beta version when the stable version is available?

Comment: Now i changed to stable version 6.0.0 and still it is not working. I want to click enter button on keyboard please have a look into attached screenshot above.

Comment: you cannot click on the enter button of keypad, all you can do is send "Enter" keyevent which is alternate of enter key on keypad

Comment: Yeah. i'm just explaining my need. And its not working. I see after entering the text some hit action is performing but not ENTER key. If it is performing enter key my app should load the content

Comment: can you please confirm if the input text field is selected while you press Enter key? you can try `driver.findElementById("id of text input).click();` and perform above code.

Comment: Yes, i have clicked and passed the keyword then performing enter keyevent.

Comment: i'm doing in these steps, 
step1 : `driver.findElement(By.id("id")).click();`
step2: `driver.findElement(By.id("id")).sendKeys("akoon");`
Step3: `((AndroidDriver<MobileElement>) driver).pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.ENTER));`

Comment: Bro, problem is from application side, they have not added onKeyListener() method. Thanks for your time. Now problem resolved.

Comment: I used the code to search product in amazon app search box, once the line ((AndroidDriver) driver).pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.ENTER)); is executed, its reseting the app, clearing the text i entered before. any help?